# Form API: Hiding form option on node forces node to be unpublished

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7

I'm creating a node through a node add form. The settings are such that it should by default be published. I'm trying to hide some of the options from the user, but when I

```
hide($form['options']);
```

for some reason the node does is no longer published by default. I've tried tracing out the value of that portion of the form

```
drupal_set_message('Options'.'<pre>'.   print_r($form['options'], TRUE) .'</pre>');
```

and I get the same values when the field is visible as when it is hidden. Seems like perhaps something is fishy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to hide it and still get it to work correctly. I had to dig into the options object and set a number of parameters to true. Not sure if I needed to do this to them all, but here is the code.

```
    $form['options']['status']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
    $form['options']['status']['#input'] = TRUE;
    $form['options']['status']['#return_value'] = TRUE;
    $form['options']['status']['#value'] = TRUE;
    $form['options']['status']['#checked'] = TRUE;
```

This is inside the hook_form_alter() function in a custom module

Comment: Actually, also found that if you set the type of the field to hidden, it still works, but does not display, you can do it like this             $form['field_name']['und'][0]['nid']['#type'] = 'hidden';

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the form['options'] array you essentially set it to 0.  Which means the published field will always be 0 (unpublished).  Try hiding the fields with CSS or JS if you need it to be conditional.

Comment: is this true of any form? or just the options portion of the form. did unset do this as well, I know that was the way to do it in drupal 6